# Puppeteer: How to enable Local Overrides in headless Chrome?

Tags: overriding, puppeteer, local, google-chrome-headless

Such option is available in normal mode using Chrome DevTools (Sources>Overrides).

I am trying to find the corresponding command line parameter in [switches list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but with no success so far.

How can I launch headless Chrome with local overrides directory in Puppeteer?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a direct way to do it, and it is not mentioned in the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) either. However, you can [intercept your requests](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) to achieve it, and probably do it more flexibly. Here is an example for overriding a single file:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/my/file.js', 'utf-8');

await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url() === 'https://www.google.com/file.js') {
        interceptedRequest.respond({
            body: data
        });
    } else {
        interceptedRequest.continue();
    }
});
```

(The `response` object passed to `respond` is described [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-httprequestrespondresponse))